# Axios.put inside Axios.get

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to update status, but when I want to do the 'put' it's not working cause axios in axios.put is not define. Can you help me please.

```
getAbsencesByRequestId(reqId) {
    axios.get(REQUESTID_URL + reqId).then(response => {
        this.collaboId = response.data[0].collabId; 
        this.beginDate = response.data[0].startDate;
        this.finishDate = response.data[0].endDate;
        this.reason = response.data[0].type;
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.response.status)
    }) axios.put(REQUEST_URL + reqId, {
        collabId: this.collaboId,
        startDate: this.beginDate,
        endDate: this.finishDate,
        status: 'VALIDATED',
        type: this.reason
    })
},
```

Comment: Please format it so it's not on one line.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the code you're showing us. Are you positive it's that `axios.put` is undefined? It seems more likely to me that `REQUEST_URL` is undefined as you are previously using `REQUESTID_URL`. Otherwise, you might have to show us where you're getting `axios` from, as `require('axios')` does have `.put` method.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you're not doing this "inside" `axios.get`. You're doing this *after* `axios.get`, and you're not even waiting for the promise to resolve. That is, the timeline will be 1. Get request is made 2. Put request is made 3. Get or put request is responded to.

Answer (score 3):

You should manage properly the order of your requests

```
axios.get(url /*optional payload and headers*/).then((getResponse) => {
  //do GET stuff with response
}).then(() => {
  //do PUT call
  axios.put(url, /*optional payload and headers*/).then((putResponse) => {
    //do PUT stuff with response
  })
}).catch((e) => {
  //handle the error
})
```